# oracle sql hints pattern match using java

Tags: java, regex

I want regular expression to match the any of the following hints or others in the sql query in the java .

```
1. /*+ parallel */
2. /*+ first_rows  */
```

kindly let me know your comments.

Comment: you want a regexp to match that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this one?

```
/\*\+.*?\*/
```

And use DOTALL flag to let dot wildcard to match multiple lines:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/\\*\\+.*?\\*/", Pattern.DOTALL);
```